# Vis.js timeline, can't set background-image of item using the style property

Tags: css, background-image, vis.js

Using a `vis.js` timeline in my `Ionic1` app, I'm trying to dynamically set a `background-image` to my items using the `style` property.
This is my item object:

[image: screen shot 2016-09-15 at 14 06 55]

But when it is rendered the image is not displayed because `background-image` is set to `url('http')`

[image: screen shot 2016-09-15 at 14 07 34]

**NOTE** None of these works

```
style: "background-image: url(' "+ p.imageURL +" ')"
style: 'background-image: url(" '+ p.imageURL +' ")'
style: "background-image: url(\" "+ p.imageURL +" \")'
style: "background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg')"
```

What is happening? Am I doing something wrong?